# Updating HTML elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JS , and i was creating a form where i would click the save button and the entered text would shown in the page , but when i click the save button the change is shown for a sec and disappears.

Source Code :

```js
function save(){
    save_element = document.getElementById("input_element").value;
    console.log(save_element);
    document.getElementById("saved_text").innerText += save_element;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Practising JS
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="">
            Name: <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a Text" id = "input_element">
            <br>
            <button id = "ds" onclick="save()">SAVE</button>
            <h1 id = "saved_text"></h1>
            <script src="./index.js"></script>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behaviour of the `<form>` is to submit the form data to server. You need to prevent this default behaviour by using `preventDefault`.

```js
function save(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Skip default behaviour
  const save_element = document.getElementById("input_element").value;
  console.log(save_element);
  document.getElementById("saved_text").innerText += save_element;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    Practising JS
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="">
    Name: <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a Text" id="input_element">
    <br>
    <button id="ds" onclick="save(event)">SAVE</button>
    <h1 id="saved_text"></h1>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: correct as well as using a hash is also  good practice. action="#"

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Practising JS
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="#">
            Name: <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a Text" id = "input_element">
            <br>
            <button id = "ds" onclick="save()">SAVE</button>
            <h1 id = "saved_text"></h1>
            <script src="./index.js"></script>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Try `<form action="#">`, by using this your page will not be reloaded. Default behaviour of `<form action="">` is submitting, so it will reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the change disappears because the page is reloading to something blank

```
 <form action="">
```

change to a hash like

```
 <form action="#">
```

Give your Form an ID .then on you click event prevent default .... like this

```
let form = document.getElementById("MyForm");

//Custom Event ...

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
            // on form submission, prevent default
            e.preventDefault();

            //your other Code to change the text 
});
```

This will prevent the form from making your page reload

Answer (score 0):

The button has the default type `submit` and is trying to submit the form.

So if you define the button as button. It works.

```
<button type="button" id="ds" onclick="save()">SAVE</button>
```